# Measurement in Double Slit Experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, observers, double-slit-experiment, particle-detectors

In physics, the observer effect is the disturbance of an observed system by the act of observation. A notable example of the observer effect occurs in quantum mechanics, as demonstrated by the double-slit experiment. A well-known thought experiment predicts that if particle detectors are positioned at the slits, showing through which slit a photon goes, the interference pattern will disappear. This which-way experiment illustrates the complementarity principle that photons can behave as either particles or waves but cannot be observed as both at the same time.

So my question is if we have a detector measuring the which-way information of **some** photons in a light ray instead of **all** the photons then will the observer effect still occur? Will the wavefunction still collapse causing the interference pattern to disappear?

Or will we see something like partial interference, which will be comparatively faded to the interference pattern that we were getting originally, when the detectors were not placed?

Comment: All the photons behave individually .... if they just see 2 slits in the EM field , then those slits cause the bright bands. If some of the photons see the detector, they are absorbed/destroyed, if there was a way for them to continue they would NOT have the 2 slit effect ....

Comment: the complimentary concept says we cannot observe the 2 properties simultaneously ...... it does not mean that they have one property or the other ...... electrons always have both for example.

Comment: @PhysicsDave So does it mean that wave function collapse happens only because of the detectors we are using as they absorb/destroy the particles?

Comment: @PhysicsDave Also if we had some non-invasive detector which does not affect the path/flow of the particles, then they would NOT have the 2 slit effect i.e. no interference pattern formed on screen? Or is it the other way?

Comment: Yes collapse means absorption.  Double slit expt (DSE) has been done with photons first then electrons then bigger particles. Photons are not really a particle but more of a confined wave in the EM field. There is something called "weak measurement" where the path of the photon is gotten due to statistics of many photons .... that is as close as we get for non-invasive, otherwise photon is poof! For real particles (electrons, molecules) we can mess with them after the slits and that destroys the "interference" or you could say it destroys their original wave function and gives them a new one.

Comment: The EM field is causing it all to happen, for photons or particles, even before they are emitted are already interacting with the EM field (virtually, like forces/virtual photons).  If the object sees the slits than the field is what interferes and gives preferred more probable paths (Feynman path integral). Preferred paths tend to be multiples of wavelength ... math similar to the classical approach.

Comment: So hypothetically if we have a perfect and ideal non-invasive detector which does not affect the path/flow of the particles, or absorb/destroy them and still measure their which-way info, then we would continue to see the interference pattern being formed? Btw am not referring to 'weak measurement' techniques here and I am aware how they were used.

Comment: hypothetically yes.

Comment: I see. So is there any way to demonstrate this experimentally instead of just stating hypothetically? Or maybe I should ask "what if" someone is able to show this in real-life experiment?

Comment: No such thing as a non-invasive detector for photons!  Photons are the essence of the EM field .... they get created by atoms/electrons and then each and everyone of them eventually gets absorbed by an atom/electron ... that's all they know how to do ..... but they do/can get scattered, refracted, reflected, diffracted on the way as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reminding me that. What about electrons though?

Comment: The thought experiment with electrons (I can’t recall if it was actually performed)and a light after the slit still affects the electron …. So we can’t say it’s non invasive. And the electron loses its 2 slit “wave function” and gets a new boring (no interference) one … if it’s unlucky enough to have met the photon

Comment: I see, understood. Thanks again, it was nice time learning new stuff from you!

Answer (score 1):

1. First, a specific detector setup for the double slit:

You can place a polarizer in front of each slit (2 total polarizers), and orient them parallel relative to each other (0 degrees apart). If the loss of interference were a result of photons passing through or otherwise interacting with the polarizers, then no interference pattern would result.  But that is not what happens.

In actual experiments, it is the *relative* orientation of the 2 polarizers - and nothing else - that determines whether or not there is an interference pattern. If the polarizers are parallel, there IS the usual interference pattern. If the polarizers are perpendicular (90 degrees apart), there is NO interference pattern. Either way, the total intensity of the resulting pattern is the same. See:

https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/files/science-demonstrations/files/single_photon_paper.pdf

The general explanation is that if it is possible to learn the which slit information - even if it is not known - there will be no interference. You could learn it by checking photon polarization. That polarization becomes a sort of marker, as explained in the paper.

"Even if not actually measured, the mere possibility that an observer could determine which slit the photon passed through causes the interference pattern to switch to non-interference."

2. Second, to your specific questions:

The above setup used a stream of individual photons rather than a beam of higher intensity with many photons.  The rule is the same either way.  What is not mentioned above is that you can choose to orient the polarizers at ANY angle relative to each other.  If 45 degrees apart, for example, half of the photons will interfere with each other and half will not.  The result is a mixing of the patterns, what you call "comparatively faded".  By adjust the relative angles, you can achieve whatever mixture of patterns you desire.

Comment: Thank your for the link to „Young's double-slit experiment with single photons and quantum eraser“ by Wolfgang Rueckner and Joseph Peidle. Brilliant experiment.